# Join 2 tables with different data types

Tags: sql, database, sqldatatypes

I am trying to join 2 tables with different data types. The data is the same but the tables were setup with the data being different data type an int and string. For the example below I want to pull the city and population. I didn't create the table and don't have access to change them.

Table 1

zip code : '12345' (Data type string)

population: 99

Table 2

Zip Code : 12345 (Data type int)

City: Danville

```
SELECT
table1.population,
table2.city
FROM table1
JOIN table2 
on tabel1.zip as CAST(table2.zip AS VARCHAR(5))
WHERE table2.city = 'Danville'
Group by 1,2;
```

Thanks

Comment: Should be possible to cast the numerical colum to a string `SELECT CAST(t1.zip_code AS VARCHAR(5))`, but you need to test yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Zip codes should not be stored as numbers!  Just ask anyone in Massachusetts or Puerto Rico about the importance of leading zeros.  I suspect you have similar issues in other countries that use numeric postal codes.

My recommendation is that you fix the data.  You don't specify the database you are using, but you should change the integer zip code to a five-digit zip code with leading zeros.

You can work around the problem in the short term by converting.  I would recommend converting to a number:

```
cast(table2.zip as int) = table1.zip
```

However, you might get conversion errors if you have malformed zips in `table2`.

Comment: Thank you, sadly I didn't build the table and don't have the access to change the table.

Comment: @NTruth . . . In any case, you want to cast to the number not to a string.  Otherwise you lose leading zeros.